# Replacing @SpringApplicationConfiguration by @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with kinda lot unit tests. All the test classes are not annotated. They all just extend the following Abstract Class where they got their annotations from too:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { MoneyjinnConfiguration.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
@SqlGroup({ @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = { "classpath:h2defaults.sql",
        "classpath:testdata.sql" }) })
public abstract class AbstractTest {

}
```

Since Spring Boot 1.4.0 `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is deprecated. I tried to replace it by `@SpringBootTest` and `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MoneyjinnConfiguration.class })` but now all my tests are failing with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto-configuration attributes found. Is org.laladev.moneyjinn.businesslogic.service.impl.ContractpartnerAccountServiceTest annotated with EnableAutoConfiguration?
```

When I now annotate the concrete test-class with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` it continues to work again.

Honestly - I don't want to modify all my test classes by moving the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from the abstract class to all concrete test classes. I kinda liked the approach of having all annotations in one central place - my `AbstractTest` class.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `@EnableAutoConfiguration` shouldn't have been on your testclass in the first place. The `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` should point to the class that is your application, which in turn should contain the `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.